# Xcode 7.1.1 No Output in Console

Tags: ios, xcode

I am using Xcode 7.1.1 and am not able to get any output in my console. I have tried deleting Xcode (including the terminal Developer files) and reinstalling numerous times. Xcode 7.1.1 would work for a while and then revert back to being unable to show output in the console. Moreover, I have also found that when this happens, the Simulator doesn't work and the playground opens up but has no output as well. Any ideas on how this issue can be addressed?

Comment: I have run into the same problem. Same version of Xcode. Somehow the output in the console came back after a restart, but the OpenGL output does not show any more. For instance, if you have an error in the fragment shader of an SKSpriteNode. Before Xcode printed the error on runtime and marked the errors in the OpenGL .fsh code editor. I think this is a genuine bug and needs reporting to Apple.

Comment: Do we have any option other than waiting for Apple to fix this? Currently, I can't test my code using the Xcode IDE and also the stop button is unresponsive! I was wondering if there were some kind of online Xcode environment that's stable that I could use in the meantime?

Comment: I could stop the program but still no output.